# Touchpad scrolling behavior

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch

So I installed Ubuntu on my new (old) Thinkpad X1 carbon Gen 6. Everything runs pretty much perfectly.
Right now, when I scroll through pages on the touchpad, the page moves when I move my fingers and stops as soon as I stop my fingers. I would like to be able to "swipe" on the touch-pad and have the page continue moving after I lifted my fingers and be able to "catch" it a a certain place when I press them down again, which is how it behaves on windows. Is there any software/driver that can do this?